# How to differentiate two templates in XSL?

Tags: xml, xslt

This is what I'm trying to do in XSL:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="document('a.xml')//row"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="document('b.xml')//row"/>

<xsl:template match="row">
  <!-- for document a.xml -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="row">
  <!-- for document b.xml -->
</xsl:template>
```

Doesn't work as is now, for obvious reasons. How can I differentiate these two templates? Document `a.xml` and `b.xml` are absolutely identical in terms of XML structure.

Comment: @Dimitre the variant suggested by Michael is not that elegant, mostly because there is a duplication of document names.

Comment: Dr. Kay's proposed solution eliminates the need to use modes -- this is something huge. Try at least once to partition an XSLT application in two different modes, and, especially in XSLT 1.0, you are bound to have hard time, a lot of duplication of templates across modes, etc. A template can match a node just using a specific predicate -- it isn't necessary to use modes. When applying templates on a node-set with nodes from the different documents one needn't analyze to determine which node is from which document. You just write a single and very simple `<xsl:apply-templates>`.

Comment: String `'a.xml'` will appear twice in my XSL file. Right?

Comment: No string will appear -- you can (and most probably should) pass the document URIs as external parameters. In XSLT 1.0 the document URI should appear in the match pattern (because in XSLT 1.0 variable references aren't allowed in the match pattern). Even in this case you don't need to use modes and it is a huge win. In the general case in XSLT 1.0 it isn't necessary to hardcode the URI "twice" as the `<xsl:apply-templates>` may select a mixture of nodes (from both documents) contained in external parameters. BTW, Dr. Kay's answer now has more upvotes than the accepted answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`mode` attribute](http://zvon.org/xxl/XSLTreference/Output/xslt_apply-templates_mode.html).

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="document('a.xml')//row" mode="a"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="document('b.xml')//row" mode="b"/>

<xsl:template match="row" mode="a">
  <!-- for document a.xml -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="row" mode="b">
  <!-- for document b.xml -->
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the mode attribute as suggested, though this does mean that the decision is made partly at the xsl:apply-templates level and partly by the template rule itself. If you want the control to be purely in the template rule, you could use the match patterns

```
row[(/) is document('a.xml')]
row[(/) is document('b.xml')]
```

(If you're still using XSLT 1.0, replace "`A is B`" by "`generate-id(A) = generate-id(B)`")

Comment: I was going to give the same answer befor I noticed this one. +1.

Comment: The solution doesn't work with Xalan 2.7.1 (XSLT 2.0), and leads to `SystemId Unknown; Line #96; Column #63; Expected ], but found: is`

Comment: Xalan 2.7.1 doesn't implement XSLT 2.0